# ngStyle directive not works on ng-template

Tags: angular, typescript, swiper.js

I'm trying to apply a custom style to a ng-template with ngStyle directive, I want to make a Slider that shows info of movies using Swiper for Angular, if I remove the ngStyle directive the Slider works, only when I add the directive the Slider doesn't work.

slider.component.html:

```
    <swiper [config]="swiperConfig">
      <ng-template 
        swiperSlide 
        *ngFor="let movie of movieList | slice:0:10" 
        [ngStyle]="{
            'background-size': 'cover', 
            'background-image': 'url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original' + movie.backdrop_path + ')'
        }">
        <div class="movie-description">
            <h3>{{ movie.title }}</h3>
            <p>
                {{ movie.overview }}
            </p>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
   </swiper>
```

slider.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Movie } from 'src/app/interfaces/movie-listings-response';
import  SwiperCore, { Navigation, SwiperOptions } from 'swiper';

SwiperCore.use([Navigation]);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() movieList: Movie[] = [];
  baseURLImage: string = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original';
  
  swiperConfig: SwiperOptions = {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 20,
    navigation: true
  };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.movieList);
  }
}
```

components.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SliderComponent } from './slider/slider.component';
import { SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavbarComponent,
    SliderComponent
  ],
  exports: [
      NavbarComponent,
      SliderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
      CommonModule,
      RouterModule,
      SwiperModule
  ],
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

The project successfully compiled, the errors are showing in the console browser:
[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LzSe.png)

Comment: You can't put element attributes on an <ng-template> since it doesn't map to an actual DOM element. add ngStyle inside div of ng-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ng-template>` does not get rendered in the DOM. It is there to help us use structural directives `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`, etc and custom directives. Same for `<ng-container>`. So ngStyle won't work on `<ng-template>` What you can do is to either apply those styles to the `<div>` inside the `<ng-template>` or you could add another `<div>` whose purpose is only for styles, for example :

```html
    <swiper [config]="swiperConfig">
      <ng-template 
        swiperSlide 
        *ngFor="let movie of movieList | slice:0:10">
        <div 
          [ngStyle]="{ 'background-size': 'cover', 
         'background-image': 'url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original' + movie.backdrop_path + ')'
        }">
           <div class="movie-description">
               <h3>{{ movie.title }}</h3>
               <p>
                   {{ movie.overview }}
               </p>
           </div>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
   </swiper>
```

Comment: This works only if the HTML elements are visible in code. If they are rendered by a structural directive like swperSlide it will not work. (Example: Conditional classes like .active, .center, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

`<ng-template>` tag is not finally rendered as a HTML tag by angular. Only the content inside the tag is used as required. So adding any attributes, styles on `ng-template` tag will not have any effect.

Add to a some element inside the `ng-template` like a `div`

Comment: What if the elements are not visible like the answer above and are rendered by the structural directive?

Comment: maybe you can pass the styles as an input to the directive

Comment: Hi. It's a directive created by a third party, the Ngx Owl Carousel O. I tried adding inputs to `<ng-template carouselSlide>` but I got errors saying that `style` property is not present...

Comment: If you are using a third party library directive or component, check with the library documentation if they allow such configurability. If not, try asking for it as a new feature on their repo.